# Can't import large gml file into Cytoscape

Tags: import, cytoscape

I'm trying to import a large gml file but I get an error: "Bad value associated with key 'Medical'". I have looked up "Medical" and can't see anything unusual.

Is it possible to enable some detailed logging to figure out exactly what is going wrong?

I can sent the file upon request

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was too many quotes. Simple normalisation solved it.